# Switching MainPage in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, argumentexception

I have 2 pages: Page1 and Page2. I start application with Page1:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1)
```

After that i switch pages witch code:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page2)
```

And everything is ok. But, when i do this in reverse ( Page2 is first and switch with this method to Page1) i have exception:

> ArgumentException: Handle must be valid. Parameter name: instance

Why?

Comment: So you mean you do this MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1) for the reverse?

Comment: In reverse:
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page2)
and then i switching:
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Page1)

Comment: Where do you put this code? Mostly I can only put it in my app.cs, I always work with App.Current.MainPage when i'm past my app.cs

Comment: yes, app.xaml.cs

Comment: I have loginPage and MainMenuPage, when user is logged i started with MainMenuPage(Page2). Im making logout with this method:
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new loginPage) and i have this exception

Comment: It might be a bug currently in Xamarin, a workaround that I found is to either downgrade to Xamarin.Android < 7.0 or use different implementation.

Comment: the bug link: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=51478

Answer (score 0):

You can try FreshMvvm, https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm You can register Navigation stack with name and call `CoreMethods.SwitchOutRootNavigation(NavigationContainerNames.MainContainer);` to switch navigation stack.